# How to create an overlay view in Android which toggles on button click

Tags: android

I want to create and overlay view when a button is clicked. Something like clicking smileys button in Whatsapp.

> I have created a framelayout with default visibility as GONE and added an onclick listener on  smiley button to toggle its visibility.

My layout XML:

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/smileyButton"
            android:layout_width="24dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contactIconContentDescription"
            android:src="@drawable/emo_im_happy" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/smileyButton" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chat_smiley_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have added onClickListener to smileyButton which toggles visibility of chat_smiley_list.

Other than some positioning problems, I am not sure whether this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Can you post some code or describe a bit more what kind of problems you have... ?

Comment: i'd have done a dialog box with transparent background and resize/position it dynamically when its drawn on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use a Context Menu: [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)

Comment: context menu forces user to choose. I want to the overlay view to look like the part of the original view. Also the user should be able to toggle the display by clicking in the smiley button